Can parathreads keep producing blocks after being downgraded?
I'm using Zombienet to spawn a Relay and a parachain, using polkadot-v1.10.0. The parachain have async backing setup. When I downgrade the parachain to a parathread, it keeps producing and finalizing blocks.
What could be causing the Lifecycle to be "ignored?".
I'll be adding the parachain_system log to see what is happening, should I do a debug in any other pallet?
Any kind of reference for further studies are welcome, thanks :)
Edit:
Just adding a print from the relay chain state.

It's a parathread that was downgraded 50 blocks before, and still keeps producing and finalizing blocks.

With the switch to Coretime this distinguishing between parachain/parathread isn't correct anymore. When all relay chain networks have migrated to Coretime this old code can be refactored to remove this "cruft".
So, the parathread continue producing blocks with Coretime is totally normal.

No, it can no longer produce blocks.
If I remember correctly, the downgrade process takes some time to complete. Have you confirmed that your chain has successfully downgraded to a parathread?

Yes I've confirmed in the relay chain state, in the paraLifecycles, it returns Parathread.
And also at the parathreads page in the PolkadotJS ui, the head keeps updating as well.
I was kinda confused, because it never happened before. But I naively thought it was related with the async backing.
